# Schrodinger versus Interaction Pictures for Mukhanov Field $\hat{v}(\eta,\mathbf{x})$ in inflation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, cosmological-inflation

*EDIT:* This is more than anything else, a question about how to define Schrodinger-picture operators, if you are given an Interaction picture set of operators (with a time-dependent potential: in this case a mass).

I am confused about how to define the Schrodinger Picture in the standard single-field inflation picture. Here for the Mukhanov field $\hat{v}(\eta,\mathbf{x})$ we have the free Hamiltonian
$$
\hat{H}_0(\eta) = \int d^{3}\mathbf{k}\ \bigg[ \hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta) \hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}(\eta) + \omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2(\eta) \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta) \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}(\eta) \bigg] \ ,
$$
where the canonical momentum field is $\hat{p}:=\partial_{\eta}\hat{v}$ and we have a time-dependent mass that is approximately (to leading-order in small-roll parameters)
$$
\omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2(\eta) \simeq k^2 - \frac{2}{\eta^2}\ ,
$$
and where the Mukhanov field has the expansion
$$
\hat{v}(\eta,\mathbf{x}) =  \int \frac{d^3\mathbf{x}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta)\ e^{+ i \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{p}} =  \int \frac{d^3\mathbf{x}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \bigg[ \hat{u}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta) \hat{c}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta_0) + \hat{u}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\ast}(\eta) \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{-\mathbf{k}}(\eta_0)  \bigg] e^{+ i \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{p}}
$$
where $\eta_{0} \to -\infty$ is some initial time where we set up our initial conditions and the $\hat{c}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta_0)$ are ladder operators, and the Bunch-Davies modes $\hat{u}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta)$ are approximately
$$
u_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta) \simeq \frac{e^{-ik\eta}}{\sqrt{2k}}\left( 1- \frac{i}{k\eta} \right)
$$

**QUESTION:** The above defines the operators in the Interaction picture. How does one define the Schrodinger picture version of the operators $\hat{v}_{S}$ and  $\hat{H}_{0S}$?

I am extremely confused as to whether $\hat{v}_{S}$ and  $\hat{H}_{0S}$ are ($\eta$) time-dependent or not? Because the mass is time-dependent in $H_0(\eta)$ (where $H_0(\eta)$ is in the interaction picture), it would seem that this might be the case? However at the same time, usually Schrodinger-picture evolution usually does not include any time dependence, since states are the objects that time evolve in this picture.

Normally one would define the interaction-picture variable in terms of the Schrodinger-picture one, where
$$
\hat{v}(\eta,\mathbf{x}) = U^{\dagger}(\eta,\eta_{0}) \hat{v}_{S}(\eta_{0},\mathbf{x})U(\eta,\eta_{0}) \ ,
$$
for some unitary evolution operator $U_0(\eta,\eta_0) = e^{- i H_0 (\eta-\eta_0)}$. I am getting confused if this is the right approach here?

Is it true that $H_{0} \neq H_{0S}$ because of the time dependence? What is the $H_{0S}$ in this case?

**EDIT 2:** What is confusing me about the above definition of the Schrodinger picture is that if $\hat{v}_{S}(\eta_0,\mathbf{x}) := \hat{U}(\eta,\eta_0) \hat{v}(\eta,\mathbf{x}) \hat{U}^{\dagger}(\eta,\eta_0)$, then this implies that $\hat{H}_{0S} = \hat{U}(\eta,\eta_0) \hat{H}_0(\eta) \hat{U}^{\dagger}(\eta,\eta_0)$ which means that
$$
\hat{H}_{0S} = \int d^{3}\mathbf{k}\ \bigg[ \hat{p}_{S\mathbf{k}}(\eta_0) \hat{p}_{S\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}(\eta_0) + \omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2(\eta) \hat{v}_{S\mathbf{k}}(\eta_0) \hat{v}_{S\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}(\eta_0) \bigg] \ .
$$
To source of my confusion is that the mass term $\omega^2(\eta)$ is $\eta$-dependent still (not $\eta_0$-dependent): this going against my intuition as usually Schrodinger-picture operators are *designed* to be time-independent. Is this intuition ruined here by the mass being time-dependent?

Comment: I believe your definition of interaction picture is correct. Are you getting some paradoxical condition by using this definition?

Comment: @sslucifer Thanks for your response, please see my ``EDIT 2'' above. I am confused that the Hamiltonian in the Schrodinger-picture $H_{0S}(\eta)$ is $\eta$-dependent. This seems paradoxical to me because I thought Schrodinger-picture operators should be time-independent

Comment: That is because $H_0$ is explicitly dependent on time (due to $\omega (\eta)$). In the interaction picture, $H_0$ in the definition of $U(\eta , \eta_0)$ must be independent of time and the external potential can have explicit dependent on time. I cannot write whole derivation in comment, if you agree with my point then I can post the derivation.

Comment: @sslucifer I am not sure I follow, if one begins with $H_0(\eta)$ (in the interaction picture) which is assumed to depend on time, how would the above work? If you would post your derivation it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the definition of interaction picture, I took it from Bruus and Flensberg (**Many-body quantum theory in condensed matter physics**),

\begin{equation}
H = H_0 + V(t)
\end{equation}
where $H_0|n\rangle = E_n|n\rangle$.

In interaction picture,

States : $|\psi_I(t)\rangle = e^{iH_0t}e^{-iHt}|\psi_s\rangle = e^{-iV(t)t}|\psi_s\rangle$. I assumed initial time to be zero, for simplicity.

Operators : $\hat{A}_I(t) = e^{iH_0t}\hat{A}_s e^{-iH_0t}$.

Look up equation (5.8) of Bruus and Flensberg, that it is clearly written that $H_0$ must be time independent.

Now coming back to your problem, if you are defining $H_0$ to be Schrodinger's picture of original Hamiltonian which is explicitly dependent on time, then it is not possible.

One solution can be that, I take,
$$
\hat{H}(\eta) = \int d^{3}\mathbf{k}\ \bigg[ \hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta) \hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}(\eta) + \omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2(\eta) \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta) \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}(\eta) \bigg] \ ,
$$

$$
\hat{H}_0(\eta) = \int d^{3}\mathbf{k}\ \hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta) \hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}(\eta)
$$
Now notice that $H_0(\eta)$ in interaction picture is same as in Schrodinger's picture as $e^{iH_0\eta}$ commutes with $H_0$. Therefore $H_0$ cannot be time-dependent by definition even in Interaction picture. Just plugging the relation to momentum operators will show you this. So, potential can be written as
$$ \hat{V}(\eta) = \int d^3\mathbf{k}  \omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2(\eta) \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}(\eta) \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}(\eta)
$$
I naively took out unitary operator out of the integral, however it is not as trivial as it seems.

If you want to write the $\hat{V}(\eta)$ in Schrodinger's picture,
$$
\hat{V}(\eta) = \int d^3\mathbf{k}  \omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2(\eta) e^{iH_0\eta} \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}} e^{-iH_0\eta}  e^{iH_0\eta} \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger} e^{-iH_0\eta}
$$

$$
\hat{V}(\eta) = e^{iH_0\eta}\bigg(\int d^3\mathbf{k}  \omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2(\eta) \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}} \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\bigg) e^{-iH_0\eta}
$$
where $\hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}$ is the velocity operator in Schrodinger's picture. So the external potential in Schrodinger's picture which have explicit time dependence is,

$$
\hat{V}_s(\eta) = \int d^3\mathbf{k}  \omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2(\eta) \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}} \hat{v}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}
$$